# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' everytime I put MySQL command

Tags: mysql, database

I can't seem to access MySQL in my terminal at all (I am on Linux Mint - Sarah). I have restarted the service, even uninstalled MySQL server and client and installed them again, even the simplest command `mysql` get denied. Let alone command like `sudo mysql -u root`, this wouldn't work at all.

I have changed the username and password in the `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf` , restarted the service, and it still didn't work.

The error message is like this.

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Most of the questions I encountered on Stackoverflow were at least able to get the `mysql` command working and they were only denied in certain command only. This doesn't seem to be in my case.

What am I supposed to do?

EDIT:
This is my current `debian.cnf` content (after I changed it).

```
# Automatically generated for Debian scripts. DO NOT TOUCH!
[client]
host     = localhost
user     = root
password = root
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[mysql_upgrade]
host     = localhost
user     = root
password = root
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Comment: Double check your credentials.

Comment: what version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @AnnaRG are you able to log in with `mysql -u root -p` and entering the password ?

Comment: @ibnelaiq what credentials? how do I do that?

Comment: @henokg Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.27, for Linux (x86_64)

Comment: @Teneff nope. It still got the same error whether I used `mysql -u root` or `mysql -u root -p`, password or no password.

Comment: @AnnaRG " what credentials?" ...it means double-check your password.

Comment: @Adyson I am pretty sure the password is correct. I have entered the password probably hundreds of time with the same result.

Comment: @AnnaRG if the credentials in `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf` are correct and in use you should be able to login with just `mysql` (without arguments), but since you're not able to login with `mysql -u root -p` (and entering the password) you should change the root password

Comment: @AnnaRG keep in mind that there might be different passwords for `root` @ different hosts

Comment: I edited my original post to show you the content of my `debian.cnf`. @Teneff

Comment: check the value of your temporary password set by mysql on initial run `sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log`

Comment: @henokg hmmm it said that there is `No such file or directory`

Comment: what about this `/var/log/mysql/error.log` directory

Comment: it worked fine, but there is no result. @henokg

Comment: so that means you password is an empty password. just hit enter after `mysql -u root -p` and you shall see it working

Comment: @henokg I have done the no password thing multiple times before (and again today), and it's still not working. `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`. I have also done it with and without `sudo`.

Comment: you can reconfigure your mysql installation with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-yourver`